# List objects in sysdata.rda from within an R package

Tags: r

I'm building a package that contains a number of look up tables, hidden from the user by storing them in `R/sysdata.rda`. This works fine and I am able to reference them from internal package functions directly or via `get`.

Is there a way to get a vector of object names contained in `sysdata.rda` from within a function inside the package? What about as a user?

The behavior I am looking for would be similar to how `ls` lists the objects in an environment.

Comment: This is a relatively frequent question on R-devel but as far as I know there is no index of the serialized objects.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I suppose I'll have to add an object to `sysdata.rda` that lists the other objects in there.

Answer (score 1):

The way I use is to have an internal function to generate the `sysdata.R` It can then also generate the vector of names within the limited scope of the function. You can then add the list of names to `sysdata.R` itself.

Or, if it is more complicated, have the function save the tables in a new environment: you can then `ls` the new environment for the list, and save the contents into `sysdata.R`.